# Riverplot package in R - Sankey diagram colors

Tags: r, visualization, sankey-diagram, riverplot

I try to create a sankey diagram using the Riverplot package in R with fixed node and edge colors. The colors are given in separate colors in the .csv files

```
library(riverplot)

# import data
edges = read.csv("sankey_data_edges.csv")

nodes = read.csv("sankey_data_nodes.csv")


r <- makeRiver(nodes, edges)
plot( r )
```

**sankey_data_nodes.csv** contains:

```
ID  x   labels  y   col
1   1   G1  2   green
2   1   G2  1   red
3   3   G3  3   red
4   3   G4  2   red
5   1   G5  6   red
6   1   G6  5   red
7   4   G7  6   red
8   2   G8  4   red
9   1   G9  3   red
10  1   G10 4   red
11  3   G11 6   red
12  3   G12 4   red
```

**sankey_data_edges.csv** contains:

```
N1  N2  Value   col edgecol
5   4   0.098870056 yellow  col
1   11  0.124105534 red col
5   3   0.163841808 red col
2   11  0.175207813 red col
10  8   0.214996976 red col
5   12  0.330508475 red col
5   11  0.406779661 red col
9   8   0.485689676 red col
8   11  0.700686653 red col
11  7   1   red col
6   11  1   red col
```

Unfortunately the result is not what it should be according to the set colors:
[image: Riverplot result]

Errors:

- No green node (ID=1)
- Edges are black instead of red and one yellow

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the columns containing the colors are of type character. Standard read.csv makes them factor, perhaps use stringsAsFactors=FALSE.